# include fetch polyfill in Aurelia with webpack

Tags: typescript, phantomjs, webpack, aurelia

so I've noticed I'm getting this error in PhantomJs, I had thought that the polyfill was included because there's an `@type/whatwg-fetch`.

```
Error: HttpClient requires a Fetch API implementation, but the current environment doesn't support it. You may need to load a polyfill such as https://github.com/github/fetch. in spec-bundle.js (line 18057)
```

I'm not sure how to load the recommended polyfill in this webpack circumstance, what npm module do I need to install? and how do I add that to the webpack (webpack based on the typescript-weback skeleton)

tried this

```
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
import '../styles/styles.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
// we want font-awesome to load as soon as possible to show the fa-spinner

// comment out if you don't want a Promise polyfill (remove also from webpack.config.js)
Bluebird.config({ warnings: false });

export async function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  // Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  // aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');
  // if the css animator is enabled, add swap-order="after" to all router-view elements

  // Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  // aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-html-import-template-loader')

  await aurelia.start();
  aurelia.setRoot('app');

    // if you would like your website to work offline (Service Worker),
  // install and enable the @easy-webpack/config-offline package in webpack.config.js and uncomment the following code:
  /*
  const offline = await System.import('offline-plugin/runtime');
  offline.install();
  */
}
```

and here's what I installed

```
npm ls whatwg-fetch                                                slave-vi
aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0 /home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui
└── whatwg-fetch@1.0.0
```

I can see the fetch code in my app-bundle.js,but I still see PhantomJS throwing the aforementioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to do the import in the same class you set up `HttpClient`. In the case of the `typescript-webpack` skeleton this might be in `app.ts`

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';
import { Logger } from 'aurelia-logging';
import { Container, LogManager, autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Route } from './main/Route';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@autoinject
export class App {
    router: Router;
    private log: Logger = LogManager.getLogger( App );

    constructor( container: Container ) {
        let client: HttpClient = new HttpClient;
        client.configure( config => {
            config.useStandardConfiguration()
                .withBaseUrl( "http://localhost:8080/" )
                .withDefaults( {
                    credentials: 'include'
                } );
        } );
        container.registerSingleton( HttpClient, () => client );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with the package `isomorphic-fetch`, which provides a Fetch polyfill that will work in Node and the browser (with webpack and Browserify).

If you just want a browser polyfill you can just as well use the package `whatwg-fetch`.

Once you've installed `isomorphic-fetch` or `whatwg-fetch`, simply import it at the start of your entry point, before all other non-polyfill imports:

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"; // or whatwg-fetch
// Other imports go here
```

That's all there is to it! After that import window.fetch will be polyfilled if necessary!

Comment: updated question, it appears whatwg-fetch uses isomorphic fetch? and I'm stilling getting PhantomJS errors

Comment: `isomorphic-fetch` uses `whatwg-fetch` in browser contexts. The error you're still getting is because you're importing Aurelia before your polyfill. Polyfills should always go first, order of import matters here.

Comment: will try it tonight, I put it there because that's where the skeleton imports bluebird as a polyfill.

Comment: I see. I think now it might fail to work because Fetch polyfills need a globally installed Promise polyfill. I'd just completely remove Bluebird from your project, install `core-js` and add `import "core-js/es6/promise";` before your Fetch polyfill import. It'll give you standard ES6 promises everywhere (available globally as `Promise`), so I suspect Aurelia picks them up too.

There are ways to use Bluebird to provide this polyfill, and Bluebird might be slightly faster, but in this case I think it might just be easier to use a classic global ES6 polyfill when combining it with Fetch.